# PHP forloop not working with array

Tags: php, json

So I am attempting to populate a select list with one category of options in a json file ('name' in this case). I have pulled in the file and am using some of the data elsewhere with (code below) so I assume it is functioning correctly as an array.

```
<?= $jsonDecoded[$jsonCoin]->price_usd; ?>
```

Here is the loop which currently returns the correct amount of results (but blank). This was based off of a standard forloop response on many posts similar to mine, but it just will not work nor will the countless variations I have tried using names from the json. Is $key correct? my json file has no name for the index i don't think?

```
<?php 
    foreach($jsonDecoded as $key => $value){
    echo '<option value=" ' . $jsonDecoded['$key'] . ' "> ' . $jsonDecoded['$value'] . '</option>'
        ;}

    ?>
```

Here is the json before decode

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "2192.49", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "1193280000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "36074434586.0", 
    "available_supply": "16453637.0", 
    "total_supply": "16453637.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "-1.54", 
    "percent_change_24h": "11.68", 
    "percent_change_7d": "-7.51", 
    "last_updated": "1500340148"
}, 
{
    "id": "ethereum", 
    "name": "Ethereum", 
    "symbol": "ETH", 

    .etc
```

Comment: no, sorry, how to access any one of the entries (I assume as they are all at the same level, finding how to display one will be replicable), but specifically in this case the "name" field

Comment: Please update your question to express exactly what you expect as output.  Be specific, so that volunteers don't have to keep editing their answers.

Comment: I have added an update to the main text but I will go in and further clean up shortly once I have tested everything mentioned so far

Comment: You have made a mistake (which you will eventually realize).  Let me speed this up for you.  Go to https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select and switch all of the option values to `name` then submit it and see that you will always get `name` and not the text value of the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to apply duplicate value `name` to the values of each option.  Use the `<select>`'s name attribute for this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2edf7d04ff3afb572c6003b069f7299e47bc4df4))

```
$json = '[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "2192.49", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "1193280000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "36074434586.0", 
    "available_supply": "16453637.0", 
    "total_supply": "16453637.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "-1.54", 
    "percent_change_24h": "11.68", 
    "percent_change_7d": "-7.51", 
    "last_updated": "1500340148"
}, 
{
    "id": "ethereum", 
    "name": "Ethereum", 
    "symbol": "ETH"
}]';
$array=json_decode($json,true);

echo '<select name="coinname">';
    foreach($array as $a){
        echo "<option value='{$a['id']}'>{$a['name']}</option>";
    }
echo '</select>';
```

Output:

```
<select name="coinname"><option value='bitcoin'>Bitcoin</option><option value='ethereum'>Ethereum</option></select>
```

Comment: I think it must be something to do with my array, a lot of solutions posted break the page at the point when it tries to run the php

Comment: @Nexus1234 You have selected an inefficient answer that performs a conditional on every iteration.  Wasteful and will confuse future SO readers.  You don't yet realize what you need.  I'll leave my answer here until you do.

Comment: while that may be the case his answer is the first and only one to successfully pull through the data. I will look further into your code but as it stands it crashes the page. Could a server PHP Version 5.4.45 be my issue and why so many responses plunge the page into oblivion?

Comment: @Nexus1234 If you give me a pastebin or sandbox link of your actual code, I'll help you to straighten out.

Comment: Thank you for the offer but I badly need to hit the hay now. It's 5am and I have work in 5 hours. As this is only a personal project for myself, will there be any significant issues? This forloop fiasco has already drained more hours than I would have liked, but I would like to further understand how your version of this functions

Comment: @Nexus1234 Yes, the other answer will mess up your form submission data.  Come back when you've had some rest and we can chat it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149527/discussion-between-nexus1234-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 2):

Try this: You should be able to see how each json group gets looped through and how you can use it in your select options. If any of it is not clear, let me know.

```
<?php

$json = "[
{
    \"id\": \"bitcoin\", 
    \"name\": \"Bitcoin\", 
    \"symbol\": \"BTC\", 
    \"rank\": \"1\", 
    \"price_usd\": \"2192.49\", 
    \"price_btc\": \"1.0\", 
    \"24h_volume_usd\": \"1193280000.0\", 
    \"market_cap_usd\": \"36074434586.0\", 
    \"available_supply\": \"16453637.0\", 
    \"total_supply\": \"16453637.0\", 
    \"percent_change_1h\": \"-1.54\", 
    \"percent_change_24h\": \"11.68\", 
    \"percent_change_7d\": \"-7.51\", 
    \"last_updated\": \"1500340148\"
},
{
    \"id\": \"ethereum\", 
    \"name\": \"Etherium\", 
    \"symbol\": \"ETH\", 
    \"rank\": \"1\", 
    \"price_usd\": \"2192.49\", 
    \"price_btc\": \"1.0\", 
    \"24h_volume_usd\": \"1193280000.0\", 
    \"market_cap_usd\": \"36074434586.0\", 
    \"available_supply\": \"16453637.0\", 
    \"total_supply\": \"16453637.0\", 
    \"percent_change_1h\": \"-1.54\", 
    \"percent_change_24h\": \"11.68\", 
    \"percent_change_7d\": \"-7.51\", 
    \"last_updated\": \"1500340148\"
}

]";

$decode = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($decode as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($value as $key1=>$value1) {
        if($key1 == "name") { echo '<option value="' . $key1 . '">'. $value1 .'</option>'; }

        }
}
```

Comment: if you wrap your json data in single quotes, you won't have to go to the trouble of escaping everything.  Also, code-only answer are "bad" for SO.

Comment: Thanks, visualising it has made it clearer but I am still not sure how I would go about pulling through every 'name' for example in each grouping. I wasn't very clear in my op about that

Comment: Just add an if statement and check ` if ($key1 == "name") {  // do something with $value1 }

Comment: can you rewrite using the variables I have used and using echo '<option .etc? I am not seeing the results and I am wondering if something is off when I am altering to match my code/json file